# Selected item not showing in dropdown list in Edit Form

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

Eg: I have both Add form and Edit Form. When I add details in dropdown List it successfully saved in database. When I go for Edit the selected item is not showing in the dropdown list.

Code I used in EditPartial.

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Language_ID,(List<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.LanguageList,null, new { type = "text", Class = "validate[required] form-control smheight", style = " font-size:11px; padding-top:3px" })
```

Controller code

```
var _tableLanguage = db.LANGUAGES_TABLE.Select(_Log => new SelectListItem
{ 
  Text = _Log.Languages,
  Value = SqlFunctions.StringConvert((decimal)_Log.Language_ID) }
).ToList();
_tableLanguage.Insert(0, new SelectListItem { Text = "Select", Value = "0" });
ViewBag.LanguageList = _tableLanguage;
var items = new SelectList(db.LANGUAGES_TABLE.ToList(), "Language_ID", "lang");
ViewData["Language_ID"] = items;
```

Model

```
public partial class LANGUAGE_PROFFICIANCY
{
    public int Language_Proficiency_ID { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> Candidate_ID { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> Language_ID { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Does the value of `Language_ID` match one of the values of your options? What is the code for generating `ViewBag.LanguageList`?

Comment: Please delete you last comment(in future, edit your question). You have made the property your binding to a `SelectList`! Its needs to be a value type and you should not be generating the 1st `SelectList` like that. Do you have a model (what are you posting back to)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change you controller code to

```
ViewBag.LanguageList = new SelectList(db.LANGUAGES_TABLE, "Language_ID", "Languages");
```

and delete the following

```
var items = new SelectList(db.LANGUAGES_TABLE.ToList(), "Language_ID", "lang");
ViewData["Language_ID"] = items;
```

and change the view to

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Language_ID, (SelectList)ViewBag.LanguageList, "Select", new {...});
```

If the value of property `Language_ID` matches the value of one of your option values, then it will be selected in the view

Note also your html attributes are invalid. `type = "text"` makes no sense - its a `<select>` element, not a `<input type="text" ..>` element. `Class = "validate[required]` makes no sense either (no sure what you think this would do)

Comment: I would also recommend not mixing inline styles and class names. If `form-control` or `smheight` cannot be modified to include the `font-size` and `padding-top` properties, just add a new class name with those properties